# Validate method in IValidatableObject wont return ValidationResult under all scenarios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using Validate method for some conditional validation that I have to do, today while I was doing it I started thinking that my validate method. The signature is

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
```

but when I implement it wont return an Enumerable of Validation result in all conditions.

Now I might be missing something obvious here but normally compiler would complain that all code paths don't return value but it never does that for Validate method.

sample implementation

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (IsPremiumCandidateSignup && SelectedProductId < 1)
    {
        yield return
            new ValidationResult("Please choose a membership option", 
                                  new List<string> { "SelectedProductId" });
    }
}
```

so in this case it would only return when the if condition is satisfied. So would greatly appreciate if someone can explain this to me or point to some resources where I can read more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will return something if the following condition is met:

```
if(IsPremiumCandidateSignup && SelectedProductId < 1)
```

So in case it is not premium signup and no product is selected it will not return anything.